# Capistrano `cap staging deploy` fails due to app_test database missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano3

I deployed to staging, and got strange error:

```
INFO [3e0e4c91] Running ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec rake db:migrate on loms
DEBUG [3e0e4c91] Command: cd /var/www/loms/releases/20150608144407 && ( RAILS_ENV=staging ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundl
e exec rake db:migrate )
DEBUG [3e0e4c91]        rake aborted!
DEBUG [3e0e4c91]        ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: FATAL:  database "loms_test" does not exist
...
```

Does it really need a test DB to apply migrations?

The strangest thing is that I've deployed this app yet and that time it didn't complain. Then I wiped the application folder out and tried to deploy from the very beginning and then it started to complain.

Comment: Have you checked that you didn't have a copy and paste error in your database.yml? Perhaps you named the staging db loms_test too?

Comment: That was the first thing I did. Nope, database.yml is OK

Comment: Oh, sorry! You're right. I'd checked out wrong place. The error is in database.yml indeed. Thank you!